# JQuery Ajax: Old content flicks in before showing the loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

have a problem with my ajax code.
I have some links and a content area.
When i click on a link, i hide the content area, load the new data and show the content area again. It works, but when showing the content area, you see the old content for a short time and then it flickers to the new content.

Can i somehow let the loading screen appear for a longer time?
Also the hide function only works the first time i use a link.

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {`

```
jQuery('.ajax').click(function(){  

var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
jQuery('#ajax_content').hide('slow',loadContent);  
jQuery('#load').remove();  
jQuery('#main').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');  

function loadContent() {  
    jQuery('#ajax_content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
}  
function showNewContent() {  
    jQuery('#ajax_content').show('normal',hideLoader());  
}  
function hideLoader() {  
    jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
}  
return false;  

});
```

});

I have this ajax code from [this source](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try emptying your content element before issuing the AJAX retrieve command:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.ajax').click(function(){  

var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
jQuery('#ajax_content').hide('slow',loadContent);  
jQuery('#load').remove();  
jQuery('#main').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
jQuery('#load').fadeIn('normal');  

function loadContent() {  
    jQuery('#ajax_content').empty().load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
}  
function showNewContent() {  
    jQuery('#ajax_content').show('normal',hideLoader());  
}  
function hideLoader() {  
    jQuery('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
}  
return false;  

});  

});
```

To make the application more robust, you can also use the `.queue()` methods to build a queue of actions. Then when a user clicks another link while one is already loading, it's easy to cancel.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect. 
I will also have a look at queues!
But one problem i still have. This slide out effect only works once, slide out doesn't work. The new content just pops up...

Comment: Could you create a working example on www.jsfiddle.net and post the URL? That might enable us to tell you more.

Comment: Found out that it works on a simple html.
But i use it in Magento, and after i load the content, the sliding functions don't work anymore. I would understand it a bit more if all the functions won't work after loading, but it's only the animation. Loading works...

Maybe there is a conflict with Prototype in Magento ? 
But i use noconflictmode for jQuery...

Comment: I suggest you try temporarily removing Prototype from your test page and trying it that way. There's an official jQuery doc page about conflicts, but I believe you've already done everything it says (http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for the help!
Think there is something different i didn't bear in mind.

greets max